# grep/fetch string from the second file on basis of list in first file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I have two files and want to fetch string in second file from a list in first file. Currently I can fetch it via `grep -Fwf first.txt second.txt`, but the word count is not equivalent to first file.

`first.txt`

```
test
test1
..........
..........
.........
```

`second.txt`

```
test:x:16000:16000:Test,Test Travel,423432423423/testaddress,Opened on  apr.10.14:/testdisk/home/test:/bin/nologin
test1:x:16378:55:Test1,Test1 Travel,442342342342/testaddress1,opened on Apr.14.10 :/testdisk/home/test1:/bin/nologin
...................
...................
..................
```

Comment: What is the desired output? I don't see why `grep -Fwf f1 f2` is not working now.

Comment: **but the word count is not equivalent to first file** What does that mean? What output do you expect?

Comment: @anubhava it means the list in the fist file. For example list in a the file is 1000 and the word count from the output should be 1000 not 1001 or above.

Comment: @fedorqui the output is 1010 instead of 1000, I have used sort and uniq too, but it is not helping me.

Comment: Is not any clear where are these `100` coming from. Edit your post and give representative input and desired output. I posted an answer (working, I guess), but will keep it deleted until you provide more insights on what you are trying to do.

Comment: What are we supposed to do with a bunch of lines that say `.....`? provide concrete, testable, representative sample input and expected output.

Comment: @fedorqui your answer with awk worked can you, make it available so that i can accept it.

Comment: @user3355434 you have asked some questions so far. Get the habit of giving a better input and desired output, so that the next people reading the question can get some knowledge out of it.

Comment: @fedorqui yes sure, i will try to give better input from next time. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a piece of `/etc/passwd` and you want to get those users in the first block of text.

I guess the problem you are facing is that you want to fetch all the names that match exactly up to the first `:`.

For this, you can use:

```
awk -F":" 'FNR==NR {user[$1]; next} $1 in user' f1 f2
```

This stores all the user names from `file1` in the array `user[]`. Then, it checks which ones appear in the first column of the `file2`.

#### Test

Let's create some dummy data:

```
$ cat f1
test
test2
tes
$ cat f2
test:x:16000:16000:Test,Test Travel,423432423423/testaddress,Opened on  apr.10.14:/testdisk/home/test:/bin/nologin
test1:x:16378:55:Test1,Test1 Travel,442342342342/testaddress1,opened on Apr.14.10 :/testdisk1/home/test1:/bin/nologin
```

And run the script:

```
$ awk -F":" 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next} $1 in a' f1 f2
test:x:16000:16000:Test,Test Travel,423432423423/testaddress,Opened on  apr.10.14:/testdisk/home/test:/bin/nologin
```